# How to add space between Columns in amCharts Bar Chart to avoid overlap category

Tags: javascript, css, charts, amcharts

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "none",
   
    "dataProvider":[{"category":"sourcing\n e prime lavorazioni ","value":-2,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#f68e8c","#f6bebc"],"colorBorder":"#f45854","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":true,"labelClass":"filiera-label"},{"category":"lavorazioni intermedieeeeeeeee ","value":-1,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#f68e8c","#f6bebc"],"colorBorder":"#f45854","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":false},{"category":"lavorazioni finali ","value":2,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#add09d","#cde0cd"],"colorBorder":"#88bc72","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":false},{"category":"distribuzione ","value":1,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#add09d","#cde0cd"],"colorBorder":"#88bc72","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":false},{"category":"valore medio filiera","average":0,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#add09d","#cde0cd"],"colorBorder":"#88bc72","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":false}],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "gridColor":"#FFFFFF",
  "gridAlpha": 0.2,
  "dashLength": 0
    }],
    "gridAboveGraphs": true,
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "value"  
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "zoomable": false
    },
    "categoryField": "category",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "autoWrap": true,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
         "tickPosition":"start",
         "tickLength":20,
         "classNameField": 'labelClass'
    },
 "exportConfig":{
   "menuTop": 0,
   "menuItems": [{
      "icon": '/lib/3/images/export.png',
      "format": 'png'   
      }]  
 }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width  : 100%;
 height  : 500px;
 font-size : 11px;
} 
.filiera-label tspan {
   font-family: Arial Black;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/none.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

I'm using AmChart 3 to make a bar chart and using a different font-family for just a category (Arial Black) so I got the overlay of the category names.
How can avoid this?

[original image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rgfs.png)

I tried css rules like letter-spacing, word-spacing, small size but everything looks like ugly

is there any elegant solution? Thanks

I did a jsFiddle to try, you will see the effect just resizing the window
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/orlandoangular/onpdat4L/12/)

jsfiddle screenshot 
[jsfiddle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e98Ey.png)[Screenshot of the first answer received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbS6o.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @AndrzejZiółek It's my first question and I'm tring how to edit a question

Comment: @MarcoOrlando Click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51067391/edit) button located under your question.

Comment: Thanks @Rawrplus

Comment: @MarcoOrlando could you rather put your code inside the inbuilt jsfiddle extension on the site here? Click the "`<>`"  button from formatting options when editing your question. This will allow us to compile your code as well directly!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to prevent this from happening is to set the `overflow: hidden;` to prevent overlapping of innerHTML and `word-break: break-word;` to provide at least some form of resemblence of the words so they don't just break at random points.

Additionally, while not necessary, for visual reasons, it might be a good idea to add a bit off padding to increase some extra space between the columns `padding: 0 5%;`

Check the following snippet:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "none",
   
    "dataProvider":[{"category":"sourcing\n e prime lavorazioni ","value":-2,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#f68e8c","#f6bebc"],"colorBorder":"#f45854","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":true,"labelClass":"filiera-label"},{"category":"lavorazioni intermedieeeeeeeee ","value":-1,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#f68e8c","#f6bebc"],"colorBorder":"#f45854","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":false},{"category":"lavorazioni finali ","value":2,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#add09d","#cde0cd"],"colorBorder":"#88bc72","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":false},{"category":"distribuzione ","value":1,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#add09d","#cde0cd"],"colorBorder":"#88bc72","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":false},{"category":"valore medio filiera","average":0,"reminderPositive":999999999,"reminderNegative":-999999999,"colorFill":["#add09d","#cde0cd"],"colorBorder":"#88bc72","isImpresaInFaseFiliera":false}],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "gridColor":"#FFFFFF",
  "gridAlpha": 0.2,
  "dashLength": 0
    }],
    "gridAboveGraphs": true,
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "value"  
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "zoomable": false
    },
    "categoryField": "category",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "autoWrap": true,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
         "tickPosition":"start",
         "tickLength":20,
         "classNameField": 'labelClass'
    },
 "exportConfig":{
   "menuTop": 0,
   "menuItems": [{
      "icon": '/lib/3/images/export.png',
      "format": 'png'   
      }]  
 }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width  : 100%;
  padding: 0 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
 height  : 500px;
 font-size : 11px;
} 
.filiera-label tspan {
   font-family: Arial Black;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/none.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't still work, try to resize your window and you'll notice it

Comment: Unless I missunderstood your question it seems fine to me. Sernd me a screenshot of what's wrong with my snippet

Comment: I just add a screenshot of your code in the question, (is there another way to send screenshot?)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to add extra spacing outside of alternating between empty data items and your data items. Outside of that, you can try the following:

1) You can set the [`labelRotation` in your `categoryAxis`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelRotation) to some angle to rotate the labels so that they're less likely to overlap.

2) You can use the [responsive plugin](https://github.com/amcharts/responsive) and add rules to help tweak your axis labels at various width thresholds. For example, you can change the `labelRotation` at certain minimum widths so that they're easier to read or outright disable them at smaller widths

```
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": [{
      "minWidth": 600,  //rotate to 45 degrees when width is between 600-800 px
      "maxWidth": 800,
      "overrides": {
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelRotation": 45
        }
      }
    }, {
      "maxWidth": 599, //rotate to 90 when width is between 350-599px
      "minWidth": 350,
      "overrides": {
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelRotation": 90
        }
      }
    }, {
      "maxWidth": 349, //disable when too small
      "overrides": {
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelsEnabled": false,
          "tickLength": 0
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

Here's a demo that demonstrates this.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "none",

  "dataProvider": [{
    "category": "sourcing\n e prime lavorazioni ",
    "value": -2,
    "reminderPositive": 999999999,
    "reminderNegative": -999999999,
    "colorFill": ["#f68e8c", "#f6bebc"],
    "colorBorder": "#f45854",
    "isImpresaInFaseFiliera": true,
    "labelClass": "filiera-label"
  }, {
    "category": "lavorazioni intermedieeeeeeeee ",
    "value": -1,
    "reminderPositive": 999999999,
    "reminderNegative": -999999999,
    "colorFill": ["#f68e8c", "#f6bebc"],
    "colorBorder": "#f45854",
    "isImpresaInFaseFiliera": false
  }, {
    "category": "lavorazioni finali ",
    "value": 2,
    "reminderPositive": 999999999,
    "reminderNegative": -999999999,
    "colorFill": ["#add09d", "#cde0cd"],
    "colorBorder": "#88bc72",
    "isImpresaInFaseFiliera": false
  }, {
    "category": "distribuzione ",
    "value": 1,
    "reminderPositive": 999999999,
    "reminderNegative": -999999999,
    "colorFill": ["#add09d", "#cde0cd"],
    "colorBorder": "#88bc72",
    "isImpresaInFaseFiliera": false
  }, {
    "category": "valore medio filiera",
    "average": 0,
    "reminderPositive": 999999999,
    "reminderNegative": -999999999,
    "colorFill": ["#add09d", "#cde0cd"],
    "colorBorder": "#88bc72",
    "isImpresaInFaseFiliera": false
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "value"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "category",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "autoWrap": true,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20,
    "classNameField": 'labelClass'
  },
  "exportConfig": {
    "menuTop": 0,
    "menuItems": [{
      "icon": '/lib/3/images/export.png',
      "format": 'png'
    }]
  },
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": [{
      "minWidth": 600,
      "maxWidth": 800,
      "overrides": {
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelRotation": 45
        }
      }
    }, {
      "maxWidth": 599,
      "minWidth": 350,
      "overrides": {
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelRotation": 90
        }
      }
    }, {
      "maxWidth": 349,
      "overrides": {
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelsEnabled": false,
          "tickLength": 0
        }
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.filiera-label tspan {
  font-family: Arial Black;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/none.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks nice solutions, but I cannot change the requirements

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I used to solve is add line break each word, and set a minimun size of the chart

```
  formatCategoryLabelChart(charts) {
    _.each(charts, chart => {
     const categories = chart.compiledChart.categoryAxis.chart.dataProvider;
  _.each(categories, category => { category.category = this.addLineBreak(category.category) });
})
}

 addLineBreak(str) {
  return str.replace('\n', '' ).split(' ').join('\n');
}
```